# How do I make my young character getting shot and recovering realistic with the following narrative needs?

Tags: internal-consistency, firearms, medical

Ok so here is the scene.

I have a twelve year old human girl taking part in the capture of a spacecrafts bridge (think of a location like Star Treks Enterprise).

What happens during this scene is fairly simple:

1- She kills a member of the bridge crew with a concealed blade using surprise and speed. Said bridge crew member not wearing any body armour and is human.

2- Another member of bridge crew shoots an automatic rifle in the panic and she is hit.

3- She clicks a few buttons after being hit.

4- She then faints.

5- Another character uses a simple (but scientifically advance) First Aid kit on her wound.

6- There a period where the other characters need to get her to a real doctor that takes between thirty minutes and hour, and the possibility of her death is very real.

7- She taken to a real doctor with a relatively simple medical theatre. No magical healing beams or easy to fit cybernetics, but we can safely assume if a modern doctor in hospital has it, the real doctor will have access to it too.

8- She still mostly out cold for a few hours after… the rest of the characters need to carry her out.

9- She recovers, but has a lasting injury that’s going to make combat difficult for her going forward.

Now the automatic rifle isn’t too dissimilar from a modern gun. Since it’s also designed to be fired in a spaceship without causing too much damage to the ship itself, we can also safely assume it’s not armour penetrating or such.

The girl herself is in peek physical fitness and is highly devoted to her cause, but still a flesh and blood human at the end of the day.

Now my current working plan is to have her get shot in the leg. This will result in massive blood loss (threatening her life) and leave her with lasting damage to her leg muscles that will make fancy combat stances and running a thing of the past. However I know very little about firearm related injuries, so I don’t know if this is unrealistic or there a less obvious way to get her wounded that fits with the narrative needs of the scene.

Comment: Hit location is (quite obviously) important. But just so you know, a modern rifle gun shoots very fast in automatic mode(and more often with military armor penetrating rounds). I hope no one else gets hurt in the panic ^^'.

Comment: Why would an automatic rifle be on the bridge?  A ship is a close-quarters battle (CQB) environment, making use of a full sized rifle difficult.  It seems more likely for the crew to be carrying CQB weapons like submachine guns, shotguns, or pistols.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan In the top of the description it is mentioned the 12 year old girl for some reason is part of the capture, so presumably the spacecraft is being boarded in a military confrontation. What has me confused is if the girl killed a bridge crew member, does that mean she's part of the assault team? Why would a girl be part of the assault team? Why would a bridge crew member have automatics handy? Sounds more appropriate being shot by security who has been called in after boarders have been detected.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if it would be realistic for someone who was shot with a modern kinetic weapon to have lasting injuries?

Comment: For a bit of clarity on the scenario, the bridge crew have taken her prisoner on the misunderstanding she’s just a maid/servant for a rich noble child and plan to use her a blackmail type purposes (we will start by killing the maid).

Since they think she’s basically harmless she not being kept as secure as she should be, and she times her assault while there distracted by an external threat and in coordination with other allies on the bridge they think are mostly harmless as well.

Comment: There are 4 votes to close this question as 'too story based' but not even one comment explaining the reasoning behind these votes. How can the OP figure out what the VTCers are unhappy with? || I disagree with the close votes. The question asks for a reality check and provides all information necessary for this check. This complies with the official rules.

Answer (score 5):

**Epidural hematoma.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidural_hematoma

[image: epidural hematoma]

> Epidural hematoma is when bleeding occurs between the tough outer
> membrane covering the brain (dura mater) and the skull. Often there is
> loss of consciousness following a head injury, a brief regaining of
> consciousness, and then loss of consciousness again. Other symptoms
> may include headache, confusion, vomiting, and an inability to move
> parts of the body. Complications may include seizures.
>
> Treatment is generally by urgent surgery in the form of a craniotomy
> or burr hole. Without treatment, death typically results. The
> condition occurs in one to four percent of head injuries.

This is the one where people get knocked out; get back up and seem good, then drift out of consciousness and die a few hours later.  This is why everyone with head trauma gets a CT scan in the ED.  Death occurs because the accumulating blood presses the brain.  You can prevent it by letting the blood go somewhere else.

This totally could happen in your scenario.  Your heroine takes a glancing bullet to the skull.

[Intracranial Hemorrhage Associated with Tangential
Gunshot Wounds to the Head](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1553-2712.1998.tb02484.x)

She is knocked out for a few seconds, comes to (covered with blood - scalp wounds bleed!) and pushes her buttons.  She is ok for a few minutes then sits down to rest, passes out and seizes.  Your medic saves her by opening up her skull.  This crimps her style as regards combat for the next week or two.

Comment: ... or it crimps her style permanently, in just about any way you need for your story: Lasting damage to her balance, field of vision, fine motor skills, attention, or even more abstract concepts like self image or attachment to the cause. Brain injury can do any level of damage to anything that makes her a fighter/human/person. Also, the treatment (relieving the pressure through a hole in the skull) is pretty basic and can realistically be followed by any duration of recuperation you choose.

Comment: A "glancing bullet to the skull" would be extraordinary luck on the part of the target even for a military pistol at point blank range in the confines of the bridge.  Doing the same with an automatic rifle round at point blank range, with its much greater energy, would be nothing short of miraculous.

Comment: Seems the perfect sort of injury for her to suffer in regards to scene structure, through from the sounds of it an automatic rifle shot might be the wrong means.  Considering she fighting people with a considerable size advantage on her in an environment full of metal surfaces, perhaps changing the source of injury to getting her head smacked against a console by one of the crew might be better?

Comment: Also I like the idea of the head injury permanently damaging her balance. Even a relative minor loss in balance at the wrong moment could be fatal in a fight or doing some acrobatic stunt, but would be of little consequence if years later she went into politics or administration.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the real-world effects of the barbarous practice of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneecapping, you could say that the round impacts the victim's knee causing a bone fracture severe enough to cause permanent damage and limping.   For the severe bleeding, you'd want another bullet opening up the [femoral artery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femoral_artery).

Consider having the fictional crewperson having the weapon set to 3-round [burst fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_mode_(weapons)) to contrive this situation to give you up to 3 rounds striking the victim.